# Axios instance does not attach Authorization header in GET requests despite attaching it in POST requests

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I use axios to call my API(Django server) from a react website, I want an authorization header with a Bearer token to be present in every request in the authorization header.

This is how I set the authorization header
`apiClient.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =` Bearer ${token}`;`

When I call my api with a post request:
`const response = await apiClient.post('posts/', payload);`
It works as expected, the authorization token is present in the request.

However whenever I call any GET request:
`apiClient.get(`posts/${router.query.id}/`),`
I see no Authorization header in the requests header in the network tab of the browser.

I verified that it is the same axios instance and that it is not an issue of an incorrect request.
I also noticed that before each POST request an OPTIONS request is being sent, perhaps it is somehow telling axios to attach authorization header?

Thank you in advance, if needed I can attach also the code in the backend responsible for the API endpoints.